# Interact with HTML5 video player in a WebView (Windows Store app)

Tags: webview, windows-8, html5-video, code-behind, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store app I have a WebView to display a video:

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" />
```

In the Code-Behind (C#) I then navigate to my video:

```
string EmbedUrl = "http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4";
string EmbedCode = String.Format("<video id=\"Video1\" width=\"853\" height=\"480\" controls=\"controls\" autoplay=\"autoplay\"><source src=\"{0}\" type=\"video/mp4\" /></video>", EmbedUrl);
MyWebView.NavigateToString(EmbedCode);
```

Then I get a nice HTML5 Video Player:

[image]

Now I would like to access this player with C# to start or stop the video. I would also like to be notified in my Code-Behind when the user switches to full-screen mode.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem!

Comment: Yes, I switched to the Microsoft Player Framework which makes things much more easier: https://playerframework.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create in the webview element also a  part for 'function pause(){}' and 'function play()'.

Then just call that in your xaml.cs this code

```
webview.InvokeScript("pause", null);
```

"pause" is the name of the javascript function in that webview element.